# monoDevelop ubuntu c# Class List has not the elementAt method

Tags: c#, ubuntu, monodevelop

I'm trying to run c# on Ubuntu. So, I downloaded the `monoDevelop` from the Software Center which version is `3.0.4.3`.

I think the problem is about the c# class library version, but i don't know where to see it or to apply a more recent one so that I could use the `elementAt` method in the `List` Class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the documentation there is an indexer that you can use instead: http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3aSystem.Collections.Generic.List%3cT%3e.Item

**EDIT**

You do use an indexer just like you would do for retrieving/setting an array element :

```
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("hello !");
        var s = list[0];
```

Comment: Ohh, nice one ;) I've been reading more about it and I found something about targeting the c# .net to 4.0. What do I need to do that ?

Edit: Thanks